# Regression Model still autocorrelated after applying the Cochrane-Orcutt method

Tags: r, regression, time-series, autocorrelation

I have determined first order autocorrelation AR(1) in a linear regression model, by analyzing the ACF as well as the PACF plots. I now want to estimated a GLE model by applying the Cochrane-Orcutt method.

I am using R, in particular the orcutt package. The output I get after applying the Cochrane-Orcutt algorithm in R is:

```
 Call:
 lm(formula = Data_y ~ Data_x)

                              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 4.8117e+01 6.8774e-01  69.964 < 2.2e-16 ***
Data_KS80_2030$Residuallast 1.3034e-03 2.9580e-05  44.064 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 10.1791 on 8757 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1815 ,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.1814
F-statistic: 1941.6 on 1 and 8757 DF,  p-value: < 0e+00

Durbin-Watson statistic 
(original):    0.66236 , p-value: 0e+00
(transformed): 1.90825 , p-value: 8.377e-06
```

The Durbin-Watson statistic indicates that my data is still autocorrelated. Is anyone familiar with the package and the method in general? Should I just reapply the Cochrane-Orcutt method to the newly generated model?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method but I'd like to point out that package nlme allows modelling different ARMA autocorrelation structures.

Comment: Hello @Roland. I was originally trying to model an OLS type linear regression model. I then tested it for autocorrelation, which prooved to be true (AR(1) model appearently). The Cochrane-Orcutt method is a way of estimating the GLE model, given you have an AR(1) type model. So I am not trying to model any type of ARMA function, my ultimate goal is to retain the structure of an OLS model by estimating the GLE model.

Comment: Well, that's easy `library(nlme); gls(Data_y ~ Data_x, correlation = corCAR1(form = ~ timevariable))`. The advantage is that this approach allows you to model and compare higher order autoregressive processes (you say "AR(1) model **appearently**") for the residuals (see `help("corARMA")`) and to include a time variable (instead of simple data order).

Comment: Oh alright - thank you for that! Maybe I am just stupid right now, but what does time variable mean in this context?

Comment: A variable giving date and time of an observation. E.g., hours since start of the measurements.